# How do I see which packages are loaded?

Tags: package

After quite some hacking I now longer get a warning from a package, did I have success? How do I list all loaded packages? (NOT INSTALLED, installation was not the problem, loading was, eg require).

Comment: What does `C-h v load-history` tell you?

Comment: I think your terminology is a bit off: an Emacs Lisp file can be loaded, a feature can be required, and a package can be activated. A single package can consist of many files and provide many features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember, the variable `package-activated-list` is what you are looking for.

Source: [A Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3qtnwo/emacs_whats_the_best_way_to_1_save_a_list_of_the/) (retrieved today, 2018-08-28)

Comment: that function doesn't exist in my emacs,
ironic though, that thread you linked is what I'm building right now: https://github.com/jappeace/linux-config/blob/master/emacs.nix Almost perfectly reproducible (cause nix).

Comment: @JappieKerk It's a variable, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Paradox package manager](https://github.com/Malabarba/paradox). With paradox loaded, `M-x paradox-list-packages` shows new, available, installed, built-in, obsolete and incompatible packages. Just scroll through the list to see what's up.

Additionally, Paradox is a really slick package manager, allowing you to upgrade available packages, delete packages that have been installed and many, many more useful tasks.

Comment: You might want to add a link to Paradox, for reference.

Comment: The question is about loaded packages, isn't it? Or all installed are loaded? But that probably also holds with the builtin package manager. Although I'm not sure how they will react if you move some folder.

Answer (score 2):

`use-package` users may set `(setq use-package-compute-statistics t)` enables one to run `M-x use-package-report` to provide output similar to:

```
Package                   Status        Last Event              Time
org-ref                   Initialized   2022-01-28 Fri 14:27    0.01
ox-gfm                    Declared      2022-01-28 Fri 14:01    0.00
ob-restclient             Configured    2022-01-28 Fri 14:27    0.00
```

ref: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#gathering-statistics

As a useful aside, [Omar](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2221/omar)'s comment led me to `C-h v features` providing a list of loaded *features* which is roughly equivalent to a superset of the loaded *packages*, as most packages use a `provide` function.

Answer (score 0):

From the "require" help:

> require is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
> ...
> If FEATURE is not a member of the list ‘features’, then the feature is
> not loaded; so load the file FILENAME.

So look in the global list "features".